# SQLAlchemy class have a class variable not instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I write some domain class like :

```
class Klient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'klient'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('pg_klient_index', 'nums', 'sals', 'k_id'),
    )
    def __init__(self):
        self.dogovors=list()
    adrrab = Column(String(200))
    c1uid = Column(String(45))
    cods = Column(String(10))
    d_first = Column(Date)
    d_vidan = Column(Date)
    docum = Column(String(40))
    doljn = Column(String(160))
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('klient_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    inn = Column(String(15))
    izm = Column(Date)
    k_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    .....
    vidan = Column(String(300))
    xmldat = Column(Date)
    xmlnum = Column(String(15))
    zak = Column(Numeric(1, 0))
    dogovors = []
```

I select all records with code:

```
klients = ss.query(Klient).all()
for k in klients:
    q = ss.query(Dogovor).filter(Dogovor.sals == k.sals, Dogovor.kl_id == k.k_id).all()
    if len(q):
        k.dogovors.extend(q)
```

And I see unexpected behavior:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Every object have a same instance of **dogovors** how it possibly?

UPD:

I tried write:

```
class Klient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'klient'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('pg_klient_index', 'nums', 'sals', 'k_id'),
    )
    def __init__(self):
        self.dogovors=list()
    adrrab = Column(String(200))
    c1uid = Column(String(45))
```

But I have the error `AttributeError: 'Klient' object has no attribute 'dogovors'`

Comment: you made everything else other than `self.dogovors=list()` class variables

Comment: Why are you manually doing what `orm.relatuonship` is for?

Comment: Relationship even. Damn mobile keyboard and sausage fingers.

Answer (score 0):

[Some docs about that](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html)
If SQLAlchemy create instance of class it didn't execute **init** method. If you need to execute some method, you need mark it with `@orm.reconstructor`

Аfter that everything works as it should:

[image]

[image]